# How to deal with lifetime when implementing async timer?

Tags: asynchronous, timer, rust, async-await

## Background

I'm developing a database manager via http connection in Rust. The database has a authenticaition-expiration strategy, and I need to persist the connection in my database manager by re-login after the expiration time.

## Pseudocode

My database manager is `Database`, and there are some methods of it:

```rust
struct Database {
    access_token: Option<String>
}

impl Database {
    async fn login(&mut self, auth: Option<String>) {
        if let Some(auth) = auth {
            // If user provide auth, login with auth

            let response = do_log_in(auth).await;
            // get access_token from response
            self.access_token = Some(response.access_token);
        } else {
            // If user doesn't provide auth, login with access_token
            do_log_in(access_token).await;
        }

        restart_timer();
    }

    // restart the login timer
    fn restart_timer(&mut self) {
        self.cancel_timer();
        self.do_start_timer();
    }
}
```

## My implementation

I use tokio to implement the `restart_timer` thing:

- First, I add a field `timer: Option<tokio::task::JoinHandle>` to `Database`
- Then, when `do_start_timer()` is called, use `tokio::spawn` to spawn a new task and assign the returning join handle to `self.timer`.
- Inside the `tokio::spawn` closure, I await the `tokio::time::delay_for`, then await the `login`.
- To cancel the timer, I just assign `self.timer` with `None`, making the task detached.

## Problem

In the detail code of the above implementation, there is a touch thing:

```rust
self.timer = Some(tokio::spawn(async move {
    tokio::time::delay_for(/* ... */).await;
    self.login().await;
}));
```

The above snippet is in the `do_start_timer` thing, but this can't compile:

```
expected `&mut Database`
found `&mut Database`
but, the lifetime must be valid for the static
```

I don't know what to do.